# How do I unlock the Barbarian and Series EV in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: pc, dungeon-defenders

The **Barbarian** and **Series EV** hero classes are currently locked to me. However, unlike with the Crystals, it does not list the requirements needed to unlock them.

What do I need to do to unlock these classes? Finish the game once, get a certain achievement, or something else? I'm currently playing the Steam version, if that matters.

Comment: Since they released this for Steam on Tuesday it might help to identify the platform as I know the game was released for Android phones a while ago.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was an Android version. I'll add that to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hearing the developers when they [played a few rounds with TotalBiscuit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xu4w2AT3tw) they mentioned adding more content later on.  I don't know how far into this video it was, or if it was in part 2.  But they mentioned that PC players got a preview of things to come in the future.  It made me believe that this was the case, for those additional characters.

To elaborate, [TotalBiscuit specifically made comments](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2xu4w2AT3tw#t=909s) about some characters being locked out, and that is what prompted them to say something with regards to PC players getting to see a little bit of what's coming in the future.

Comment: Can you point out in the video where those comments are made and throw it in a link in your answer (just right click the video where the comments are made and get a URL with the time in it)? I couldn't find it skipping through and it'll make it more clear for others who have this question. I'll accept then. :)

Comment: I will do that when I get home from work later.  I'll try to find it and mark that.  Sorry I didn't already--not an avid Youtuber.

Comment: I went through and found the part in the video and added the link.

Comment: Hey, is this answer still up to date?

Comment: @badp the answer below is now the correct answer: the Barbarian and Series EV (and the Jester and the alternate gendered heroes) have been added to the game as paid DLC.

Answer (score 3):

These characters are now available as two separate pieces of paid DLC.